# Como puedo agregar dos x-data y dos x-show en un mismo div en alpinejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind, alpinejs

He estado haciendo un header para mi sitio web, y en ella le estoy agregando alpinejs con tailwind, pero tengo un problema. Y es que tengo que meter dos x-data en un mismo div para ocultar dos menus y más abajo necesito agregar dos x-show para mostrar el contenido en un mismo div, estaba pensando en hacer como una especie de funcion pero nose como hacerlo.

En el codigo podemos observar dos x-data="{ openMenuBar: true }" x-data="{ openMenuProfile: true }"  , en openMenuBar se usara para cerrar un slider Bar y la vez podra abrir un de nuevo el menu con un button icon, en el tamaño de un celular ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en x-data="{ openMenuProfile: true}" se usara para cerrar el menu del perfil

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo

```
<div class="min-h-full" x-data="{ openMenuBar: true }" x-data="{ openMenuProfile: true }">
    <div class="relative z-40 lg:hidden" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" x-show="openMenuBar" x-show="openMenuProfile">

        <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-75"></div>

        <div class="fixed inset-0 flex z-40">


            <div class="relative flex-1 flex flex-col max-w-xs w-full pt-5 pb-4 bg-white">

                <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 -mr-12 pt-2">
                    <button type="button" x-on:click="openMenuBar = !openMenuBar"
                        class="ml-1 flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white">
                        <span class="sr-only">Cerrar Barra Lateral</span>
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                            viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                        </svg>  
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!--  Logo in Mobile -->
                <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center px-4">
                    <img class="h-8 w-auto"
                        src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-purple-500-mark-gray-700-text.svg"
                        alt="Workflow">
                </div>

                <!-- List of Options in Mobile -->
                <div class="mt-5 flex-1 h-0 overflow-y-auto">
                    <nav class="px-2">
                        <div class="space-y-1"> 
                            <a routerLink="/home"
                                class="bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base leading-5 font-medium rounded-md"
                                aria-current="home">
                                <!--Heroicon name: outline/home Current: "text-gray-500", Default: "text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500" -->
                                <!-- Home Logo -->
                                <svg class="text-gray-500 mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor"
                                    aria-hidden="true">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                        d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6" />
                                </svg>
                                Inicio
                            </a>

                            <a routerLink="/home"
                                class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base leading-5 font-medium rounded-md">
                                <!-- Heroicon name: outline/view-list -->
                                <svg class="text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2"
                                    stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                        d="M4 6h16M4 10h16M4 14h16M4 18h16" />
                                </svg>
                                Mis Tareas
                            </a>

                            <a routerLink="/home"
                                class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base leading-5 font-medium rounded-md">
                                <svg class="text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2"
                                    stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                        d="M12 8v4l3 3m6-3a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                                </svg>
                                Reciente
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mt-8 ">
                            <h3 class="px-3 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                                id="mobile-teams-headline">Equipos</h3>
                            <div class="mt-1 space-y-1" role="group" aria-labelledby="mobile-teams-headline">
                                <a routerLink="/home"
                                    class="group flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-base leading-5 font-medium text-gray-600 rounded-md hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">
                                    <span class="w-2.5 h-2.5 mr-4 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="truncate"> Ingeniería </span>
                                </a>

                                <a routerLink="/home"
                                    class="group flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-base leading-5 font-medium text-gray-600 rounded-md hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">
                                    <span class="w-2.5 h-2.5 mr-4 bg-green-500 rounded-full" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="truncate"> Recursos Humanos </span>
                                </a>

                                <a routerLink="/home"
                                    class="group flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-base leading-5 font-medium text-gray-600 rounded-md hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">
                                    <span class="w-2.5 h-2.5 mr-4 bg-yellow-500 rounded-full" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="truncate"> Cliente Exitoso </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-shrink-0 w-14" aria-hidden="true">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Static sidebar for desktop -->
    <div 
        class="hidden lg:flex lg:flex-col lg:w-64 lg:fixed lg:inset-y-0 lg:border-r lg:border-gray-200 lg:pt-5 lg:pb-4 lg:bg-gray-100">

        <!-- Logo in Desktop -->
        <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 px-6">
            <img class="h-8 w-auto"
                src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-purple-500-mark-gray-700-text.svg" alt="Workflow">
        </div>

        <!-- Sidebar component, swap this element with another sidebar if you like -->
        <div class="mt-6 h-0 flex-1 flex flex-col overflow-y-auto">
            <div class="px-3 relative inline-block text-left">
                <div>
                    <button type="button"
                        class="group w-full bg-gray-100 rounded-md px-3.5 py-2 text-sm text-left font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-100 focus:ring-purple-500"
                        id="options-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                        <span class="flex w-full justify-between items-center">
                            <span class="flex min-w-0 items-center justify-between space-x-3">
                                <img class="w-10 h-10 bg-gray-300 rounded-full flex-shrink-0"
                                    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502685104226-ee32379fefbe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=3&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                                    alt="">
                                <span class="flex-1 flex flex-col min-w-0">
                                    <span class="text-gray-900 text-sm font-medium truncate">Jessy Schwarz</span>
                                    <span class="text-gray-500 text-sm truncate">@jessyschwarz</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <!-- Heroicon name: solid/selector -->
                            <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor"
                                aria-hidden="true">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                    d="M10 3a1 1 0 01.707.293l3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 5.414 7.707 7.707a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l3-3A1 1 0 0110 3zm-3.707 9.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 14.586l2.293-2.293a1 1 0 011.414 1.414l-3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-3-3a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                                    clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>


                <!-- Options of Profile-->
                <div class="z-10 mx-3 origin-top absolute right-0 left-0 mt-1 rounded-md shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 divide-y divide-gray-200 focus:outline-none"
                    role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="options-menu-button" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="py-1" role="none">
                        <!-- Active: "bg-gray-100 text-gray-900", Not Active: "text-gray-700" -->
                        <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                            id="options-menu-item-0">Ver Perfil</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                            id="options-menu-item-1">Configuración</a>
                        <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                            id="options-menu-item-2">Notificaciones</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="py-1" role="none">
                        <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                            id="options-menu-item-4">Soporte</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="py-1" role="none">
                        <a routerLink="/signup" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem"
                            tabindex="-1" id="options-menu-item-5">Registrarse
                        </a>
                        <a *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn | async)" (click)="verifyLooged()" routerLink="/login"
                            class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                            id="options-menu-item-5">Iniciar Sesión</a>

                        <a *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)" (click)="onLogout()"
                            class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                            id="options-menu-item-5">Cerrar Sesión</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <nav class="px-3 mt-6">
                <div class="space-y-1">
                    <!-- Current: "bg-gray-200 text-gray-900", Default: "text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50" -->
                    <a href="#"
                        class="bg-gray-200 text-gray-900 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md"
                        aria-current="page">
                        <!-- Heroicon name: outline/home Current: "text-gray-500", Default: "text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500" -->
                        <svg class="text-gray-500 mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6" />
                        </svg>  
                        Menu Principal
                    </a>

                    <a href="#"
                        class="text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md">
                        <!-- Heroicon name: outline/view-list -->
                        <svg class="text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2"
                            stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M4 6h16M4 10h16M4 14h16M4 18h16" />
                        </svg>
                        Mis Tareas
                    </a>

                    <a href="#"
                        class="text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md">
                        <!-- Heroicon name: outline/clock -->
                        <svg class="text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2"
                            stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                d="M12 8v4l3 3m6-3a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                        </svg>
                        Reciente
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-8 pt-24">
                    <!-- Secondary navigation -->
                    <h3 class="px-3 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                        id="mobile-teams-headline">Equipos</h3>
                    <div class="mt-1 space-y-1" role="group" aria-labelledby="mobile-teams-headline">
                      
                        <a routerLink="/home"
                            class="group flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-base leading-5 font-medium text-gray-600 rounded-md hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">
                            <span class="w-2.5 h-2.5 mr-4 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="truncate"> Ingeniería </span>
                        </a>

                        <a routerLink="/home"
                            class="group flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-base leading-5 font-medium text-gray-600 rounded-md hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">
                            <span class="w-2.5 h-2.5 mr-4 bg-green-500 rounded-full" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="truncate"> Recursos Humanos </span>
                        </a>

                        <a routerLink="/home"
                            class="group flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-base leading-5 font-medium text-gray-600 rounded-md hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">
                            <span class="w-2.5 h-2.5 mr-4 bg-yellow-500 rounded-full" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="truncate"> Cliente Existoso </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Main column -->
    <div class="lg:pl-64 flex flex-col" >
        <!-- Search header -->
        <div class="sticky top-0 z-10 flex-shrink-0 flex h-16 bg-white border-b border-gray-200 lg:hidden">
            <!-- Sidebar toggle, controls the 'sidebarOpen' sidebar state. -->
            <button type="button"  x-on:click="openMenuBar = !openMenuBar"
                class="px-4 border-r border-gray-200 text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-purple-500 lg:hidden">
                <span class="sr-only">Open sidebar</span>
                <!-- Heroicon name: outline/menu-alt-1 Selector Menu Bar Mobile -->
                <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2"
                    stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M4 6h16M4 12h8m-8 6h16" />
                </svg>
            </button>

            <!-- Search -->
            <div class="flex-1 flex justify-between px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="flex-1 flex">
                    <form class="w-full flex md:ml-0" action="#" method="GET">
                        <label for="search-field" class="sr-only">Buscar</label>
                        <div class="relative w-full text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-600">
                            <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pointer-events-none">
                                <!-- Heroicon name: solid/search -->
                                <svg class="h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                    fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                        d="M8 4a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8zM2 8a6 6 0 1110.89 3.476l4.817 4.817a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4.816-4.816A6 6 0 012 8z"
                                        clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            <input id="search-field" name="search-field"
                                class="block w-full h-full pl-8 pr-3 py-2 border-transparent text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-transparent focus:placeholder-gray-400 sm:text-sm"
                                placeholder="Buscar" type="search">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="flex items-center" >
                    <!-- Profile List Dropdown Phone -->
                    <div class="ml-3 relative" >
                        <div  >
                            <button type="button"  x-on:click="openMenuProfile = !openMenuProfile"
                                class="max-w-xs bg-white flex items-center text-sm rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-purple-500"
                                id="user-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                                <span class="sr-only">Abrir Menu de Usuario</span>
                                <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                                    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502685104226-ee32379fefbe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                                    alt="">
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <!--
                            Dropdown menu, show/hide based on menu state.
                            Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
                            From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                            To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                            Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
                            From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                            To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        -->

                        <div class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 divide-y divide-gray-200 focus:outline-none"
                            role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu-button" tabindex="-1">
                            <div class="py-1" role="none">
                                <!-- Active: "bg-gray-100 text-gray-900", Not Active: "text-gray-700" -->
                                <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                                    id="options-menu-item-0">Ver
                                    Perfil</a>
                                <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                                    id="options-menu-item-1">Configuración</a>
                                <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                                    id="options-menu-item-2">Notificaciones</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="py-1" role="none">
                                <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                                    id="options-menu-item-4">Soporte</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="py-1" role="none">
                                <a routerLink="/signup" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem"
                                    tabindex="-1" id="options-menu-item-5">Registrarse
                                </a>
                                <a *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn | async)" (click)="verifyLooged()" routerLink="/login"
                                    class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                                    id="options-menu-item-5">Iniciar
                                    Sesión</a>

                                <a *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)" (click)="onLogout()"
                                    class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"
                                    id="options-menu-item-5">Cerrar Sesión</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <main class="flex-1">
            <!-- Page title & actions -->
            <div class="border-b border-gray-200 px-4 py-4 sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-between sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="flex-1 min-w-0">
                    <h1 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 sm:truncate">Menu</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4 flex sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4">
                    <button type="button"
                        class="order-1 ml-3 inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-gray-700 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-purple-500 sm:order-0 sm:ml-0">Share</button>
                    <button type="button"
                        class="order-0 inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-purple-600 hover:bg-purple-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-purple-500 sm:order-1 sm:ml-3">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pinned projects -->
            <div class="px-4 mt-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">

            </div>

            <!-- Projects list (only on smallest breakpoint) -->
            <div class="mt-10 sm:hidden">

            </div>

            <!-- Projects table (small breakpoint and up) -->
            <div class="hidden mt-8 sm:block">

            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

Que opciones podria hacer para arreglar este codigo, muchas gracias?

Comment: ya no ya pude resolver gracias

Comment: Y si ya pudiste resolverlo, antes que dejarnos a todos con lo duda, no es mejor que escribas la respuesta de como se soluciona?